# F# pipelines and LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, f#, pipeline

I'm starting to learn F#. I'm finding quite dificult to change my mind from OO programing. I would like to know how would a F# developer write the following:

**"Traditional" C#**

```cs
public List<List<string>> Parse(string csvData){
    var matrix = new List<List<string>>();
    foreach(var line in csvData.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.None)){
        var currentLine = new List<string>();
        foreach(var cell in line.Split(','){
            currentLine.Add(cell);
        }
        matrix.Add(currentLine);
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

**"Functional" C#**

```cs
public List<List<string>> Parse(string csvData){
    return csvData.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.None).Select(x => x.Split(',').ToList()).ToList();
}
```

The Question is: *Would the code below considered right?*

**F#**

```ml
let Parse(csvData:string) = 
    csvData.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()
    |> Seq.map(fun x -> x.Split(',').ToList())
```

Comment: Some offtop. What you want to achieve using `csvData.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(),...`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your translation looks good to me. The use of extension method in C# (such as `foo.Select(...)`) is roughly equivalent to the use of pipeline and F# function from `List`, `Seq` or `Array` modules, depending on which collection type you're using (e.g. `foo |> Seq.map (...)`).

It is perfectly fine to use LINQ extension methods from F# and mix them with F# constructs, but I would only do that when there is no corresponding F# function, so I would probably avoid `ToArray()` and `ToList()` in the sample and write:

```
open System

let Parse(csvData:string) = 
    // You can pass the result of `Split` (an array) directly to `Seq.map`
    csvData.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.None)
    // If you do not want to get sequence of arrays (but a sequence of F# lists)
    // you can convert the result using `Seq.toList`, but I think working with
    // arrays will be actually easier when processing CSV data
    |> Seq.map(fun x -> x.Split(',') |> Seq.toList)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things not very F#-ish in your solution:

- mutable `List` is named [ResizeArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353447.aspx) in F# and they don't have good support as built-in collections including Array, List, Seq.
- You don't often need to use LINQ in F#, Array, List and Seq modules are more than adequate.
- dot (.) syntax doesn't play nicely with pipe operators.

Changing the return type to `string [] []`, you could make more succinct code with a helper function:

```
let split (delim: string) (str: string) =
    str.Split([|delim|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

let parse (csvData: string) = 
    csvData
    |> split Environment.NewLine
    |> Array.map (split ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are subtle differences between the various solutions on this page. For example, your C# solutions and pad's solution are eager, but your F# version and Tomas' are lazy. Yours and pad's split on `Environment.NewLine`, but Tomas' splits on *any* char in `NewLine` (I'm guessing you want the latter since you called the overload that accepts `StringSplitOptions`). Maybe these matter; maybe not.

Anyway, here's a different take on pad's solution.

```
let split (delims: char[]) (str: string) =
  str.Split(delims, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

let parse csvData =
  let nl = Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()
  [ for x in split nl csvData -> split [|','|] x ]
```